# How I can change the condition or compare operator for WP_Query in pre_get_posts

Tags: wp-query, mysql, get-posts, sql, pre-get-posts

So here is my problem
I want to show Posts if have same category if not have post then show post of same tag. And to do that I am using "pre_get_posts" action. and setting query like following.

```
function related_custom_posts($query){
   $query->set( 'category__in', array(2,3) );
   $query->set( 'tag__in', array(10,13) );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'related_custom_posts', 1 );
```

But it create sql like this
`AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (11) )` but i need this with OR condition `AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) OR tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (11) )`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the OR relation using the [`tax_query` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) like so:

```php
$query->set( 'tax_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'terms'    => array( 2, 3 ),
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
        'terms'    => array( 10, 13 ),
    ),
) );
```

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ